# MoxieManager double extensions error

Tags: tinymce-4, moxiemanager

I'm using MoxieManager (http://www.moxiemanager.com)inside TinyMCE. Now i get this error message on loading: "Double extensions is not allowed for security reasons".

My configuration seems to be normal, there are no double extensions :

```
$moxieManagerConfig['filesystem.extensions'] = 'jpg,jpeg,png,gif,docx,doc,xls,xlsx,zip,pdf';
$moxieManagerConfig['edit.extensions'] = 'jpg,jpeg,png,gif';
$moxieManagerConfig['view.extensions'] = 'jpg,jpeg,png,gif,pdf';
```

any ideas what could be wrong? thanks for your help.

best regards
thomas

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue as well when working locally and found that it was because of a directory name that was part of my web root. In my case, my web root existed under a client folder named "*Company Inc*". It was the "*inc*" that matched and was throwing the error. When I updated my directory names to safer values all fired correctly.

The error gets triggered under moxiemanager/classes/Util/PathUtils.php around line 303 if you want to check the `preg_match` pattern.